# Expanding my search function

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am looking at trying to expand my search function for my small project.  Right now I have the ability to search using a char field but I want to add a few checkboxes.  Some projects have been flagged with the SRED checkbox and I want to be able to also search for SRED only projects.

Here is my current search setup.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
...     
proj_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Project Name')
pre_quote = models.CharField(max_length=3)
quote = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Quote #', unique=True)
...
SRED = models.BooleanField()
...
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def search(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SearchProjectForm(request.POST)
    if not form.is_valid():
         return render_to_response('project/search.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        projects = Project.objects.filter(proj_name__icontains = form.cleaned_data["text"])
        companies = Clients.objects.filter(client_name__icontains = form.cleaned_data["text"])
        return render_to_response('project/search.html', {'form': form, 'projects':projects, 'companies': companies}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

form = SearchProjectForm()

return render_to_response('project/search.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
class SearchProjectForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(label = "Search")
```

search.html

```
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
<h3>Search Results</h3>
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks again

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass project to Form constructor and then add box fields if necessary:

```
form = SearchProjectForm(project, request.POST)
```

and:

```
class SearchProjectForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(label = "Search")

    def __init__(self, project, *args, **kwargs):
      form = forms.Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      if project.has_additional_fields():
        self.fields['additional_field'] = forms.SomeField()
      if project.only_additional_fields():
        self.fields['text'].required = False
```

More here: http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/

Comment: hey thanks for the quick response.  With putting that code in, I am now getting a 'TypeError at /search/

__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)' error.  It points to: form = SearchProjectForm() of my views.py.

Comment: You need to pass project to the SearchProjectForm in constructor. First code line of my answer :-) In the second instantion of form too :) So `form = SearchProjectForm(project)`.

Comment: :) I tried that and keep getting a name error for project when doing it

Comment: Is your search performed in context of some project? You must retrieve this project from the database and pass it there.

Comment: Yes thank you, I got it right after I posted the last comment.  Thank you!

Comment: One last thing, is it possible to search by just the additional field?  Im trying to test it but it says I the charfield is required

Comment: Yes, I have edited my answer, to show you how to achieve this.